# How to fix "Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml)" error installing Ripple - yum

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, ripple

I installed the [Ripple rpm repo](https://ripple.com) following [documentation](https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/#installation-on-centosred-hat-with-yum)

> (step 1)
>
> $ sudo rpm -Uvh
> https://mirrors.ripple.com/ripple-repo-el7.rpm

Then (step2) I run command:

```
sudo yum install --enablerepo=ripple-stable rippled
```

but I get the error:

```
https://mirrors.ripple.com/rpm/%24releasever/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: ripple-stable. Please verify its path and try again
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

That error message occurs when attempting to install the rippled package on an unsupported environment.

The rippled rpm package is currently [only available for CentOS/RHEL 7](https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/#system-requirements) (and Ubuntu 15+ using alien)

You could try installing with:

```
sudo yum install --enablerepo=ripple-stable --releasever=el7 rippled
```

but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

\The URL is suspect - it says `%24releasever` which is URL-encoded `$releasever` which means your `yum` isn't filling in that blank, e.g. `.../rpm/7/stable/`.

Try hard-coding it in the file you can find in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` that your step one installed.